# Recording from Mic and Exporting / POSTing it as FLAC format? - Desktop AIR, AS3, Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe, microphone

Hi all I'm fairly new to handling voice / mic in AS3 but I am currently in a situation where I need to retrieve a voice input via the mic, and then I'd have to be able to get it as a FLAC audio format then POST it to our server.

Would be nice if I wouldn't need to write the binary FLAC data to a file before POSTing but if that's something unavoidable, I guess it's all okay.

I will be developing it for a Mac and a PC on the Adobe AIR platform. **NOT FOR THE MOBILE (yet).**

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need an ecternal conversion application, like [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and then communicate with it through [NativeProcess](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html)

Comment: I found out about SoX which is also a Terminal / COmmand Line utility. Is that any better? And also, this does mean that I have to write the file outside the bounds of the AIR app then right?

Comment: Don't know SoX. You can also use the [flac command line tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flac/files/flac-win/) itself. And yes that will create a local file (which you can delete once uploaded of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/lukeweber/flac-as3-alchemy-wrapper) library. According to the authors, you can convert raw data (retrieved directly from micro, here, they use the term rawPCMByteArray - Pulse-code modulation), to .flac file.